# 'Can not resolve action' at partialview in ASP.NET MVC Shared Area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I am working on ASP.NET MVC3. I have a partial view `RestaurantAdminNavigation.ascx` which i moved from `Views/Restaurant` Folder to `Views/Shared` Folder.

I have a action link in that view

`<%:Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Restaurant", new {  id=Model.OId }) %>`

It was working fine when it was at `Views/Restaurant` folder but after moving at `Views/Shared` folder, if I keep the parameters as a part of that action link, it shows me an error 'Can not resolve action edit'. But if i keep

`<%:Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Restaurant") %>`

it does not show me error.

After Googling i understand the reason might be registering the routes. I need to register route in Global.ascx file but i can not understand what might should  I code if this is the solution.

Comment: Can you provide the code in your RestaurantController's Edit action?

Comment: By the looks of it, it should work without issues. Do you have any attributes applied to this action? Do you have another overload of Edit action in that controller?

Comment: no overload except the HTTP Post.

Comment: The ActioLink by default generates a GET request so HTTP Post actions would not work here. What amazes me though is, how it works without Id parameter. I'm still feeling there is an Edit action which does not accept id parameter

Comment: Hi. thanks for your responses. now it is taking the URL as http://localhost/mysite/Restaurant/Edit?Length=10

Comment: For your kind info OId (String) is 10 character in length. if i see the source of the html it is displaying  <a href="/Instantfetch/Restaurant/Edit?Length=10" id="R000000001">Edit</a>

Comment: i guess it is happening because of map routing in Global.ascx file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a wrong [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx) of the ActionLink helper:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Edit",                  // linkText
    "Edit",                  // actionName
    "Restaurant",            // routeValues
    new { id = Model.OId }   // htmlAttributes
) %>
```

And here's the [correct one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Edit",                  // linkText
    "Edit",                  // actionName
    "Restaurant",            // controllerName
    new { id = Model.OId },  // routeValues
    null                     // htmlAttributes
) %>
```